# If a person has haram money and he invests in the business, is the profit permissible for him?

Tags: halal-haram, business, investment

BY **haraam** ways I have earned money suppose ($1000) and invest this all money in a business.
What if I earn like $1500 through legal business and does a charity of invested money ($1000), then the profit income (*$500*) be will my income be halaal or haraam ?.

Answer (score 0):

**Nope.**
That haram money won’t give you any significant rewards even if you put it in a good charitable cause.

Comment: the profit will consider haram, even after giving charity of investing money?

Comment: @SyedHamza yes. Because the way you’ve achieved that money is haram, anything you will do with it won’t change the fact it’s haram.

Comment: one last question, if we invest suppose ($100) in the haram business and gain $150 as result, after realizing that he can just take genuine money (invested money $100) and charity all other money ($50). Then his money ($100) is halal or haram?

Comment: @SyedHamza why would it be halal in the first place when you’re investing in a haram company? It’s like investing in a porn company knowing what they’re doing is haram, but still receiving a shared portion. It doesn’t matter what good you’ll do with that money, that money itself will be haram regardless of what benefit you put it to use.

Answer (score 0):

Even though you do charity of the complete amount but still the money will be considered Haram as it is earned by wrong means.

Suppose you steal $1000 from someone and afterwards you donate that amount to a church. But if you are caught and put to trial, you can't tell the judge not to punish you just because you later donated that amount.

Hope I have cleared out my point

Comment: thanks for guiding me. one last query, we can also not borrow money for investment from that person who has haram money?

Comment: Well bro this is a real complicated question to me as I myself had been trying to get an answer similar to this question. My question was “I had been invited to a person for dinner but I’m not sure that if that person earns halal or haram”. To this question, I got almost the same answer from most of the scholars, which is “If you are sure that person earns haram then don’t go but if you are not sure about it then just Bismillah”. I think this goes the same for your question as well.